# count of executors in Jenkins cluster

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins cluster, has `1-Master with 2-Executor and 1-Agent with 2-Executor` and now  how to get the total number of executors in my Jenkins cluster using java or groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the script console, you can run something like this:

```groovy
final jenkins = Jenkins.instance

jenkins.computers.inject(0) { acc, item ->
  acc + item.numExecutors
}
```

If you are running this in a sandboxed pipeline, you will have to have the methods whitelisted by an administrator in the *In-Process Script Approval* (or through a plugin using whitelists) at http://jenkinsUrl/scriptApproval/. You won't be able to use `inject` right now because of [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481), but your pipeline script might look like:

```groovy
final jenkins = Jenkins.instance

int executorCount = 0
for (def computer in jenkins.computers) {
    executorCount += computer.numExecutors
}

// Rest of pipeline
```

If your pipeline does not run in sandbox, you may have access to those objects without whitelisting.

Comment: `import jenkins.model.Jenkins
node{    
final jenkins = Jenkins.instance
jenkins.computers.inject(0) { acc, item ->
  acc + item.getNumExecutors()
}
  def output = sh script: "java -jar /home/user1/earms/hazelcast/TestbedThreads.jar", returnStdout:true}`  
When I try to run the above code with pipeline..I am getting the following exception:                                                          `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: 
Scripts not permitted to use method jenkins.model.Jenkins getComputers'

Comment: and I tried approve the following: Jenkins->ManageJenkins->in-process script approval-> approved jenkins.model.jenkins..but not working..could you please help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: @User12345 are you running using the script console (http://jenkinsUrl/script), or through a pipeline script? If you are running through a sandboxed script you will need permission to do that.

Comment: @User12345 OK then, you are going to have to have certain methods whitelisted on Jenkins in order to make calls like this about the Jenkins instance you are running on.